# Reference elements in GwtBootstrap3 in code

Tags: gwtbootstrap3

I'm very new to GWT and GwtBootstrap3 so this might be a dumb question, but how can the elements from my ***.ui.xml file be referenced in the code?

For example, I have a paragraph in my ***.ui.xml file -

```
    <b.html:Paragraph alignment="LEFT">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </b.html:Paragraph>
```

and I want to be able to change the text in my code. 
Similarly, if I'm creating a List but can't statically provide the list elements in my ***.ui.xml file and need to provide them in my code, based on what choices are available, is there a way to do that?

Any suggestions/comments will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rohit, I noticed in your answer you changed your initial paragraph widget to a Label element. For anyone else visiting this question and wanting to work specifically with paragraphs: adding the attribute `ui:field="myWidget"` to an html Paragraph Element will allow you to perform this task directly

**UIBinder**

```
xmlns:b.html="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.html"    

<b.html:Paragraph alignment="LEFT" ui:field="myWidget">
    Lorem Ipsum
</b.html:Paragraph>
```

**Java**

```
import org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.html.Paragraph;

@UiField public Paragraph myWidget;

myWidget.setText("Dynamic text");
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way finally after research into GWT UiBinder.
I inserted a Label widget in the paragraph and provided an id to my Label using *ui:field ='myWidget'* and the then referenced it in my ***UIBinder.java using:

```
@UiField Label myWidget;
```

and set the text in the constructor using

```
myWidget.setText("Dynamic text");
```

[This can also be done without using widgets](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_World)